# java: package net.serenitybdd.core.pages does not exist

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When I Compile my project I get the error:
"java: package net.serenitybdd.core.pages does not exist"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zusIw.png)

When I run the Project I get the error:
"Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins: maven-enforcer-plugin: pom: 1.4 from / to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https: // repo .maven.apache.org / maven2 / org / apache / maven / plugins / maven-enforcer-plugin / 1.4 / maven-enforcer-plugin-1.4.pom "
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcHQK.png)

I have this same Project on my local PC and it works correctly. Now that I am passing it to my work station that happens.
I was checking and it seems that McAfee-Agent Antivirus is blocking it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI6RN.png)
If you could help me it would be great, thank you.

IDE IntelliJ - Proyecto Maven

this is my POM:

4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>ToMapfre</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <serenity.version>2.0.54</serenity.version>
    <serenity.maven.version>2.0.54</serenity.maven.version>
    <serenity.cucumber.version>1.6.4</serenity.cucumber.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.54</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <AlwaysPass/>
                        </rules>
                        <fail>true</fail>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*RunnerTest.java</include>
                </includes>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.maven.version}</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                    <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>serenity-reports</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: What IDE version do you use? Make sure you try it with the 2021.1.1 version. If problem remains, please clarify - can you build from command line by Maven? Attach somewhere full [idea.log file](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#logs-directory) to see what happens.

Comment: I tried those options, but the same message I get.
I have been checking and I see that in the Remote machine where I am passing my project, the IDE does not have the libraries, for some reason it is not downloading the libraries. Is there any reason why it doesn't? How could I configure it?

Comment: What is the result of the `mvn clean compile` command in command line for this project?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Delete .idea folder.
2. in .m2/repository/ find problem dependencies and delete they too.
3. Than open project from pom.xml (from menu -> Open - Projects folder -> pom.xml)

Sometimes helps.

Comment: The same message appears when Compiling and Running the project.

Comment: have you tried re-importing the maven project in IntelliJ? (`Ctrl-Shift-O` under Windows) Otherwise `re-import all maven projects` under the maven tab.

Comment: I tried those options, but I get the same message.
I have verified that in the IDE of my local machine (personal) if it has the libraries. But in my Remote machine I see that it does not have the libraries, for some reason it is not downloading the libraries, I understand that IDE downloads them when compiling, but here it does not download them and the message of the packages is displayed ...
How can I do ?

Comment: Have you any custom settings in \.m2\settings.xml ?
Also, you can try this: In Idea go to: File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Maven -> Importing. Add VM options for importer:
`-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true   
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true `  
And the same in Build, Execution, Deployment -> Maven -> Runner -> VM Options.